# Scanning for Nearby BLE Devices python program

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, iot, beacon

scanning a beacon for raspberry pi

i have tried with pybluez package it found error that gatlib missing.when gatlib installed in RPI3 it again shows same error

```
from bluetooth.ble import DiscoveryService

service = DiscoveryService()
devices = service.discover(2)

for address, name in devices.items():
    print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
```

> No gatlib module found in the program.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but did you misspell gattlib in your code somewhere, or only in your stack overflow question?

Comment: It is gattlib not gatlib. I was able to reproduce this error. ```ImportError: No module named 'gattlib'```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install gattlib` should work

For python3, use pip3

Make sure dependencies such as libbluetooth-dev,pkg-config,glib-2.0,lib-boost-python-dev,libboost-thread-dev are installed.

Required dependencies in gattlib module: [Link](https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/src/default/DEPENDS)